# Connecting SQL to dreamweaver php project: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, html, mysql, dreamweaver

I am new to PHP/SQL and am trying to implement it on a project based in Adobe dreamweaver (DW).

From what I've worked out so far: it seems DW is not the ideal platform to integrate PHP/SQL functionality as they do not keep their documentation up to date and [seem to be phasing out PHP functionality](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2280495).

However, I'm persevering as there are a lot of CSS/Html support functions that are useful in DW. My challenge now is to make sure I can still adequately integrate PHP so that I can make more dynamic sites. In this instance, I need to pull database information through to the html to show the status of a gift registry.

I've been following [this great resource](https://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/php-crud-tutorial-part-1) on how to set up my very first PHP CRUD. I tried to adapt their example to match my own database credentials and came across an error that I'm having trouble resolving.

The theory is that the PHP code snippet connects to mySQL database *'registry_list_baby'* in my PHP test environment (I'm using the default MAMP setup where localhost is on port 8889).

However, the data returned on the website is "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused"

Any pointers on things to try next?

```
<?php
class Database
{
    private static $dbName = 'registry_list_baby' ;
    private static $dbHost = 'localhost:8889' ;
    private static $dbUsername = 'private';
    private static $dbUserPassword = 'private';

    private static $cont  = null;

    public function __construct() {
        die('Init function is not allowed');
    }

    public static function connect()
    {
       // One connection through whole application
       if ( null == self::$cont )
       {     
        try
        {
          self::$cont =  new PDO( "mysql:host=".self::$dbHost.";"."dbname=".self::$dbName, self::$dbUsername, self::$dbUserPassword); 
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
          die($e->getMessage()); 
        }
       }
       return self::$cont;
    }

    public static function disconnect()
    {
        self::$cont = null;
    }
}
?>
```

RELATED HTML SNIPPET

```
<!-- Form fields -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h3>PHP CRUD Grid</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Taken "Claim this gift" </th>
          <th>Gifter "This gift has been claimed by XYZ"</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
<?php
   include 'database.php';
   $pdo = Database::connect();
   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM registry ORDER BY id DESC';
   foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['taken'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $row['gifter'] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
   }
   Database::disconnect();
  ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]` Connection refused error means that:

- you do not have the rights or privileges to access the database with that user,
- your database parameters are either not correct, or
- the sever where you have your database is not accessible; it may be offline.

Try checking dbUsername user privileges.

and check What Port is your Mysql is listening.